# NodeJS Express multi region user sessions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, redis

I run a website based on NODEJS deployed out of the UK on AWS using EC2 and RDS + redis (for session storage).

I am starting to get more users in Asia and am looking to expand. I have used RDS read replica and getting good performance but since my redis-session server is based in the UK it is adding 250+ms onto all requests.

Is it a good idea to use a new redis session server located near the Asia read replica + EC2 instance? My concern is if I have a load balancer in front there may be inconstancies with user sessions.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the database write performance in Asia important to you?

Comment: Not particularly since it's only going to be ajax requests to save user data rather than bulk commits. Correct me if I'm wrong but it would be impossible to have write level access across regions on separate database instances connected to the main RDS instance?